# How to copy multiple radio list buttons into a textarea and change skeleton into sound

Tags: javascript

I have no idea where to start with this and came here to learn how to do it.

I have the following radio lists and textarea(#mcsound):

```
<input type="radio" name="skeleton" id="1mcskel1" value="Top" /> Top<br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton" id="1mcskel2" value="Nose" /> Nose <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton" id="1mcskel3" value="Mouth" /> Mouth <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton" id="1mcskel4" value="Ribs" /> Ribs <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton" id="1mcskel5" value="Liver" /> Liver <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton" id="1mcskel6" value="Joints" /> Joints <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton" id="1mcskel7" value="Cap" /> Cap <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton" id="1mcskel8" value="Fibula" /> Fibula <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton" id="1mcskel9" value="Ball" /> Ball <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton" id="1mcskel1" value="Sea" /> Sea <br /><br /><br />

<input type="radio" name="skeleton2" id="2mcskel1" value="Top" /> Top<br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton2" id="2mcskel2" value="Nose" /> Nose <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton2" id="2mcskel3" value="Mouth" /> Mouth <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton2" id="2mcskel4" value="Ribs" /> Ribs <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton2" id="2mcskel5" value="Liver" /> Liver <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton2" id="2mcskel6" value="Joints" /> Joints <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton2" id="2mcskel7" value="Cap" /> Cap <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton2" id="2mcskel8" value="Fibula" /> Fibula <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton2" id="2mcskel9" value="Ball" /> Ball <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton2" id="2mcskel0" value="Sea" /> Sea <br /><br />

<input type="radio" name="skeleton3" id="3mcskel1" value="Top" /> Top<br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton3" id="3mcskel2" value="Nose" /> Nose <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton3" id="3mcskel3" value="Mouth" /> Mouth<br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton3" id="3mcskel4" value="Ribs" /> Ribs <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton3" id="3mcskel5" value="Liver" /> Liver <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton3" id="3mcskel6" value="Joints" /> Joints <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton3" id="3mcskel7" value="Cap" /> Cap <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton3" id="3mcskel8" value="Fibula" /> Fibula <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton3" id="3mcskel9" value="Ball" /> Ball <br />
<input type="radio" name="skeleton3" id="3mcskel0" value="Sea" /> Sea <br /><br />
Sound:<br/> <textarea name="sound" type="text" rows="6" cols="30" id="mcsound"></textarea><br/><br/>
```

The JSFiddle can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/Lpm38noj/2/

Okay now what I'm trying to do is add the following to match the above values.
1. Top = Tah, Dah
2. Nose = Nah
3. Mouth = Mah
4. Ribs = Rah
5. Liver = Lah
6. Joints = Juh, Shuh, Chuh
7. Cap = Cah, Kah, Gah
8. Fibula = Fah, Vah
9. Ball = Bah, Pah
0. Sea = Sah, Zah
etc..

So if from the 3 radio lists I select 1 radio button from each and have 146 for example in the textarea it would say:

**EDIT: Update** I would like 1. 4. 6. Instead of 123 sorry, I did have the numbers below but stackoverflow numbered list changed my numbers.

1. Tah, Dah
2. Rah
3. Juh, Shuh, Chuh

3 rows for the 3 radio buttons within the textarea. I hope this makes sense?

I'm stumped as how to do this, I wouldn't even know where to start. :(

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I did it using pure javascript:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpm38noj/4/

```
// Holds currently selected radio values, initialized to empty strings
// Use the radio button names so we can have a dynamic function set them
var skeleton = {
    "skeleton": "",
    "skeleton2": "",
    "skeleton3": ""
};

// Defines each radio values sound
var sounds = {
    "Top": "Tah, Dah",
    "Nose": "Nah",
    "Mouth": "Mah",
    "Ribs": "Rah",
    "Liver": "Lah",
    "Joints": "Juh, Shuh, Chuh",
    "Cap": "Cah, Kah, Gah",
    "Fibula": "Fah, Vah",
    "Ball": "Bah, Pah",
    "Sea": "Sah, Zah"
};

// Attaches event listener to each radio button
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]');
var radio, index = 0, length = radios.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    radio = radios[index];
    radio.addEventListener('change', onChangeRadio);
}

// Updates selected value of radio button
function onChangeRadio (event) {
    var radio = event.target;
    // Use name to set currently selected object's property to radio value(sound)
    skeleton[radio.name] = sounds[radio.value];
    // Call function to update textarea value
    updateTextArea()
}

// Updates textarea value
function updateTextArea () {
    // Get text area
    var textarea = document.getElementById('mcsound');
    // Initialize new string
    var newValue = "";
    // For each selected value only set it if it has a value (\n for new lines)
    if (skeleton["skeleton"] != "") {
        newValue += "1. " + skeleton["skeleton"];
    }
    if (skeleton["skeleton2"] != "") {
        newValue += "\n2. " + skeleton["skeleton2"];
    }
    if (skeleton["skeleton3"] != "") {
        newValue += "\n3. " + skeleton["skeleton3"];
    }
    // Set built string to value of textarea
    textarea.value = newValue;
}
```

And since your previous question had to do with simplifying code if you make the first radio name `skeleton1` instead of just `skeleton` we can simplify the textarea update function to this:

```
function updateTextArea () {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('mcsound'), newValue = "", index = 1;
    for ( ; index < 4; index++) {
        if (skeleton["skeleton" + index] != "") {
            index > 1 ? newValue += "\n" : ""
            newValue += index + ". " + skeleton["skeleton" + index];
        }
    }
    textarea.value = newValue;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpm38noj/5/

**EDIT**

So here is an update to display the radio button index so you get 146 as you want. I added a new function to determine the index of the radio button:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpm38noj/7/

```
function getIndex (context) {
    var index = 1;
    while (context = context.previousElementSibling) {
        if (context.type == "radio") {
            index++;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome @AtheistP3ace works perfectly and is easy to understand. It was my mistake I was after the 1 2 3 in the texarea to be the number that is selected e.g in this example it should be: 146
1. Tah, Dah
4. Rah
6. Juh, Shuh, Chuh
Because that way I'm keep uniform, but I know I didn't specify that in the post. Either way thanks a million! But stackoverflow is changing my 1. 4. 6. to a numbered list so it reads 1. 2. 3. :(

Comment: Hello again AtheistP3ace any idea why this is not working with the previous javascript? If I enter the 3 numbers it selects them in the radio buttons. But only when I actually click on the radio buttons it adds them to the sounds textarea? https://jsfiddle.net/Lpm38noj/6/ Cheers

Comment: @aussiedan what do you expect to happen? I thought that's what you wanted. Click radio button update text area.

Comment: @aussiedan I updated with new fiddle to display 146 like you want. I am still unsure what your second comment means and what you expect to happen.

Comment: that's awesome thank you. If you see in my jsfiddle comment link I included your code from my condense my js question which you answered which included #mcnumber when I put together and type 146 into #mcnumber the radio buttons are selected. But the #mcsound requires me to click with mouse the radio buttons rather then recognising them being selected by the #mcnumber code: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpm38noj/6/

Comment: @aussiedan Here I updated the fiddle to work as you type: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpm38noj/8/

Comment: @aussiedan and here is one that handles deleting values from text field: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpm38noj/9/

Comment: Awesome @AtheistP3ace works great, thank you for all your help! Made understanding the process and theory very easy to follow!

Comment: @aussiedan happy to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Create a lookup for the sounds then use them.

I used jQuery for the input processing and events but the main idea is the lookup and using it:

```
var sounds = [
{'match': 'Top',sound: 'Tah, Dah'},
{'match': 'Nose',sound: 'Nah'},
{'match': 'Mouth',sound: 'Mah'},
{'match': 'Ribs', sound: 'Rah'},
{'match': 'Liver',sound: 'Lah'},
{'match': 'Joints', sound: 'Juh, Shuh, Chuh'},
{'match': 'Cap', sound: 'Cah, Kah, Gah'},
{'match': 'Fibula',sound: 'Fah, Vah'},
{'match': 'Ball', sound: 'Bah, Pah'},
{'match': 'Sea', sound: 'Sah, Zah'}
];

var lookup = {};
// create reference to list above and use it everywhere
lookup.list = sounds;
for (var i = 0, len = lookup.list.length; i < len; i++) {
  lookup[lookup.list[i].match] = lookup.list[i];
}

var radioGroups = '#mc-skeleton-c,#mc-skeleton-c2,#mc-skeleton-c3';

function processRadios() {
  $('#themcsound').find('textarea').text("");
  $(radioGroups).find('input:checked').each(function(index) {
    var skel = $(this).val();
    var mychoice = lookup[skel];
    var prior = $('#themcsound').find('textarea').text();
    prior = prior ? prior + "\n" : prior;
    $('#themcsound').find('textarea').text(prior +(index+1)+". "+ mychoice.sound);
  });
}
$(radioGroups).on('change', 'input[type=radio]', function() {
  processRadios();
});
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks @Mark Schultheiss even though I asked for Javascript I'm wanting to learn jQuery as well so it's good to see the contrast between your code and AthiestP3ace

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a working example implementing module pattern: [Click here to watch the JS Bin](https://output.jsbin.com/xuyeju)

This is a piece of the Javascript code to accomplish the requirement:

```
var skeleton = (function(skeletonModule, document){

  skeletonModule.soundHandle = (function(){

    var textArea = document.getElementById('mcsound');

    // Here you are saving which sounds to make depending on which value
    var sounds = 
        {'Top': 'Tah, Dah',
         'Nose': 'Nah',
         'Mouth': 'Mah',
         'Ribs': 'Rah',
         'Liver': 'Lah',
         'Joints': 'Juh, Shuh, Chuh',
         'Cap': 'Cah, Kah, Gah',
         'Fibula': 'Fa, Vah',
         'Ball': 'Bah, Pah',
         'Sea': 'Sah, Zah'};


    // This function attachs the check event to the radio buttons
    // according to the markup
    function attachCheckEvent(){
      var radios = document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]');
      var radio;
      for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        radio = radios[i];
        radio.addEventListener('change', function(){
          var that = this;
          return function(){
            // May be here you must check if radio button is checked
            // anyway, this is working for me
            textArea.value += sounds[that.value] + '\n';
          }();
        });
      }
    }

    // Here we are attaching the events to desired inputs
    function initEvents(){
      attachCheckEvent();
    }

    // This is the interface published by the skeletonModule.soundHandle module
    return {
      init: initEvents
    }

  }());

  return skeletonModule;

}(skeleton || {}, document)); // We pass to the IIFE the skeleton object. If is null we pass an empty object literal

skeleton.soundHandle.init();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: jQuery wasn't tagged in the question.

Comment: That's true. I'll fix it.

Comment: It helps thanks a lot for taking your time to help me @wilsotobianco